# Adding fragments to backStack while moving forward and on clicking back navigating in hierarchy

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am new to Android programming.
I am working on a app in which I use Fragments, and I swap the fragments with

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container,fragment)
    .addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

I want to navigate back by clicking the device back button.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this,I hope this will help

```
 FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    String tag = f.getFragmentTag(); // instance method of a to get a tag

    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.container, f, tag);
    ft.addToBackStack(tag);
    ft.commit();
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0)
    {
        fm.popBackStack();
    } else
    {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Comment: Hi Nitin, onBackPressed(), method should be defined in MainActivity?

Comment: It is not compulsory but in your case it is required.

Comment: In mainActivity that is activity in which your adding your fragments

Answer (score 0):

use some id instead of null in addToBackStack method.